# Effect of density of a fluid on laminar boundary layer thickness in external flow

Tags: fluid-mechanics, fluid

We know that laminar boundary layer thickness depends on the distance from the leading edge and also characteristics of the fluid such as approach velocity, dynamic viscosity and density.

I understand the effects of velocity, dynamic viscosity and distance to the thickness but I do not understand the relation between density and thickness. According to the mathematical relationship, a fluid with a higher density has thinner laminar boundary layer, ceteris paribus.

(1) What I thought is that when density is high, more fluid particles are in contact with the surface of the object, contributing to shear stress but this must be wrong.

How can we explain this disproportionality?

(Newtonian fluid with constant density, steady flow)

EDIT:
After learning the shear stress formula for laminar flow on a horizontal thin plate, I realized that what I thought in (1) is actually correct (the way it is correct may be wrong). For fluids for higher density, we, in fact, attain higher shear stress but this means there is disproportionality between shear stress and thickness of boundary layer at a point on the surface but this is more confusing.

Comment: Are you assuming a fluid of constant density?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention this. Yes fluid density is constant.